# javascript fake navigator

Tags: javascript

This is my script:

```
function ShowProps(obj, objName)
{
    var result = '';
    for (var i in obj) 
    {
          var obj_i = obj[i];
        result += i + ": " + obj[i] + "\n";
        alert(result); // PRINT
    }
}
var fakenav = navigator;
fakenav.platform = "fake";
navigator = fakenav;

ShowProps(navigator);
```

as you see I'm just trying to replace the "platform" property of navigator. But it's not changed and when printed it shows "Win32" but what I wanted was "fake".

what am I doing wrong?

regards!

Comment: Why you want to do so?

Answer (score 6):

For starters you can't really change the platform property of the navigator object. It's read-only!

And by assigning `navigator` to `fakenav` you aren't really making a copy of it. You are just taking a reference.

It's not clear what you are really trying to achieve but this route is probably not the way to get there..

Comment: yeah.. was updating the answer :)

Comment: guys, thanks for answer! im using GeckoFx (C#) is it possible to make changes in navigator using GeckoFX api?

Comment: added =) some time im using awesomium. its possible but works only on slow internet connection. just look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747511/awesomium-run-javascript-before-page-starts-loading